# Google query explorer

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I am developing a interface like Google query explorer (just like same) i wanna load all the available dimensions and metrics to IList or array list and display on a asp.net ListBox

Thanx.

Comment: I wanna load all the available Dimensions/Mt rices into a List rather than hard coding it in the aspx file or code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the API doesn't provide a method to get all available metrics and dimensions. So you have to hard code them.